# css: how to keep a small group of words together without linebreak and without overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a list of tags that need to be displayed next to each other, and moving to the next line if flowing out of the box.
These tags have spaces `('test completed', 'test ongoing',...),` and I want to keep the whole tag text on one line (no break in the middle of a tag).

I tried to display the tags as a span with `white-space: nowrap;` but then it flows out of the box!

So basically I need the `white-space: nowrap` within the tag, but a normal break around the tags.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you give us a code snippet so we can see how the code is laid out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code, I would try putting a parent container around your tags so you can display everything `inline-block` and make sure the width of the elements are great enough:

```css
.parent span{
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap; 
width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>test completed</span>
<span>test ongoing</span>
<span>another test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: nice and elegant solution, Thanks!

Comment: @Ben999 Absolutely!

Comment: Great, thank you! But it has to be: white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but it should works, maybe had overloaded another css rules, have a look:

```css
div {
  width: 360px;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  white-space: initial;
}
.tag {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  border: solid 2px green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="tag">adx cvxc bbgdfg </span>
  <span class="tag">adadxcz cvxc bbgdfg </span>
  <span class="tag">adadxcz cvxc bbgdfg </span>
  <span class="tag">adadxcz cvxc bbgdfg </span>
</div>
```